# Is the determinant of a skew symmetric matrix nonzero if nondiagonal entries are all nonzero?

Tags: linear-algebra, skew-symmetric-matrices

Let $A = [a_{i,j}]_{i,j} \in M_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$ be a skew-symmetric matrix such that $a_{i,j} \neq 0$, $\forall i \neq j$. I am trying to see if it's true that $\det A \neq 0$.

I tried working from the definition of $\det A$; the only useful observations I could see were that the sum over permutations reduces to a sum over permutations without fixed points, and that for a permutation $\sigma$ we have by skew-symmetry
$$
\prod\limits_{i=1}^{2n} a_{i, \sigma(i)} = \prod_{i=1}^{2n} a_{i, \sigma^{-1}(i)}
$$

But I can't see how and whether these are useful. I also know that the determinant is the square of the [Pfaffian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian), but I can't see how to use this fact either.

Comment: *“I proved that the converse holds at least.”* Actually both directions are not valid implications.

Comment: You are right, in my proof I forgot I was dealing with a sum at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is best to consider an example. Then we can see that the Pfaffian polynomial can get zero for certain choices. So let $n=2$ and consider the following skew-symmetric matrix
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 &  3  & 1  & -1  \\
-3 & 0 &  2 &  1 \\
-1 & -2 & 0 &  1 \\
1  & -1 & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Using the determinant formula for skew-symmetric matrices of size $4$, we see that $\det(A)=0$. For a $4\times 4$ skew-symmetric matrix the general formula for its determinant is
$$
(af-be+dc)^2
$$
for the matrix $A$ in $a,b,c,d,e,f$ from your wikipedia link.